# How can a buffer-overflow be an exploit for hackers?

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I've watched a video on "Buffer overflow exploit" The guy in the video writes more byte than the array can hold e.g:

```
int foo(const char* cp){
    char sz[10];
    strcpy(sz, cp); // consider cp is a pointer to 20 characters
    return x; // some valid return statement here
}
```

Above if `foo` called with an argument of 20 characters then I'm sure it Undefined Behavior. But Why he said it can be an exploit and how?

- In fact in C++ we are always strongly recommended not to do so but how can this be an exploit? Thank you.

Comment: Im not sure, is this question suitable on SO ?

Comment: Not sure SO is a good place to ask for where to find general background reading materials about basic coding security. But consider what happens if the overrun ended up changing data in an executable section, thus creating new instructions; or overwrites legitimate data to make the program do something new and nefarious; or so on.

Comment: It's pretty difficult (but not impossible) to abuse buffer overflow today. There are countermeasures, like separation of instruction memory and data memory. Check [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow?tab=Votes) (sister site to SO), you'll find much more info there.

Comment: I guess the way an overflow attack works is insert some code that can be executed. And insert with some repeated pattern or some kind of jump instruction to where the malicious code is. Probably you overwrite the function stack or something like that. Well, im not an export but its the broad idea.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages. 
We don't know your level of expertise so to answer the question correctly would result in writing a tutorial which is off-topic. Instead, tell us where you researched the question, what you tried and what is specifically wrong with what you tried. That will reduce the problem down to something specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But Why he said it can be an exploit and how?

Only some examples:

By simply overwrite other memory content which has meaningful content. Maybe you have a bool variable behind your buffer structure which contains the access right flag. Overwrite the buffer may set the access flag and the code will give access which was not the idea.

Corrupting the stack is also a bad thing. Maybe your return statement runs on wrong address are more critical execute some content of the buffer.

There are lot mot such things possible which can be find with every search engine!

Simply example of a manipulated flag access:

```
struct Check
{
    char small[4];
    bool accessGranted;
};  

int main()
{   
    Check check{ "", false };

    strcpy( check.small, "12345" );

    if ( check.accessGranted )
    {
        std::cout << "Ubs...!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

BTW: I found that a bit outdated but useful paper: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/IntrCompSec/LectureNotes_New/Buffer_Overflow.pdf

Comment: Ok thanks. One thing What is the point in doing so? "overflowing the buffer"?

Comment: In order to exploit it, surely...

Comment: You're writing code as data into memory locations that aren't actually allocated. So it ends up in your computer memory, but it's actually not part of the application. That may mean some routines like scanning / concating a string may look for a 'null-terminator' in the string, and may never find it, and keep scanning across the overflowed memory, ending up in potentially bad places.

Comment: Try to create a buffer overrun is a typical and fully automated attack technique. By automated program tracing is it possible to see when a program change execution behavior, e.g. run on different code as without overflow. So you can see that the code can be manipulated to execute the injected data. This makes it possible to get user privileges of the program or corrupt data access to databases or whatever you want.

Comment: @Maestro if say the calling code is `char buf[5]; bool authSucceeded = false; auth(...); foo(buf);` then the foo code can overwirte data after `buf` - `authSucceeded` and change the control flow to possibly bypass application checks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of conditions for this how this may be an exploit, and to list them all would take us a bit too far on this site. The basic case is quite simple but of course there are a lot of safeguards that make it hard to actually use it as an exploit. Here are a number of things that must be true for a buffer to become exploitable.

- The contents that is loaded into the buffer is such that eventually the code pointer runs across the contents of the buffer. This usually means it's large with a lot of NOP's.
- The contents of the buffer contains valid machine code. Otherwise you'd simply get an exception and program crash, duh.
- The application that started the exploitable code has priviliges that are interesting for the exploit. OS'es have lots of layers that are designed to keep out unverified or unsigned code.
- The memory usage is predictable / trainable. Modern OS'es relocate memory so that applications are no longer guaranteed fixed pointer addresses
- The processor control flow is predictable / trainable. Sometimes, the exploit needs to 'train' a processor to branch into a certain conditioned state.

Answer (score 0):

The stack holds not only your local variables, but also your return addresses, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

By overwriting the stack, you can force the CPU to jump to a location of *your* choice, which in case of an attack is a memory area that was filled with the malicious code by the attacker.

Now the computer runs the attackers code with *your* permissions.